# what are the coordinates (x,y) of a point given its distance to a line?

Tags: math, distance, equations

given the line `y=(-8/5)x-(4/5)` or `8x+5y-4` find the equation of a line that is 6 units away from the given line.
I've tried looking how to solve this problem with no luck, I have a feeling I need to use the distance between a line and a point formula and the distannce formula i just can figure out how.

`Distance formula= sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)` this should equal 6

Distance between a line and a `point= ((|Ax+By+C|)/sqrt(A^2+B^2))` this should also equal 6

what I tried doing was pluggin in the numbers and setting both of the equations equal to each other and solving for the x and y. With that I can easily fin the equation of the line.

Any suggestions on how to do this??

Comment: There are an infinite number of points that match.

Comment: This questions should be in http://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 1):

If the line is described as y = ax + b, and you want a parallel line a distance d away, the formula for that line is y = ax +b ± kd, where k = sqrt(a<sup>2</sup>+1).

As for *why*, are you comfortable with vectors?

Comment: Seeing as how the asker gives the equation in standard form as well, it's probably easier to start with that.